# Email html font size in Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, outlook-2007

```
<div style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px;">TEST</div>
```

I'm providing the above source as an html email to Outlook 2007, and it's rendering 7.5px font. Any ideas of what hack I need to make this work?

Edit: I'm setting the mail contents with `body`, like:

```
new MailMessage
{
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    Body = "<div style=\"font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px;\">TEST</div>"
};
```

I don't believe this is related though. Note that if I view source in the generated email the html is as expected. The problem seems to be only that outlook doesn't render it correctly for whatever reason.

Comment: What property are you using to set the body text? Body or HTMLBody?

Comment: @JP I will update the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that most email programs understand very little, if any, CSS. Try specifying the font details using the old, non-CSS methods. This method is deprecated, but unfortunately it is what we have to do to style the emails. It also prevents exact sizing of fonts.

```
new MailMessage
{
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    Body = "<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"1\">TEST</font>"
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I've been looking for days, this is the only true solution I found!

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- Use the **HTMLBody** property instead of **Body** when creating HTML emails.
- Do your quotes need to be escaped like that? I've never seen that before, but I'm used to VB where literal quotes are doubled.
- Check your read settings, you may be reading emails as plain text.